# categorical variables longitudinal analysis

Tags: r, regression, lm, categorical-data, panel-data

I am estimating the predictive capacity of multiple metabolites in different outcomes for a large population that has 3 follow ups. For this I am building linear regression models in two different ways:

1. using the last measurement as an outcome

```r
model <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(lastmeasure ~ i + age + sex + firstmeasure + 
    secondmeasure, list(i = as.name(x))), data = df)
})
```

2. Using  the slope (change in follow up) as outcome

```r
y=c()
N=(df$ID)
for (i in 1:length(N)){
  fit <- lm(c(firstmeasure[i], secondmeasure[i], thirdmeasure[i]) 
            ~ c(firstage[i], secondage[i], thirdage[i]), data=df)

} 

normslope <- qnorm((rank(y, na.last="keep") - 0.5) / 
      sum(!is.na(y)))

lm(normslope~sex+metabolite, data = df)
```

This works for my continuous variables, however for categorical variables (menopause) I do not know if I should code as dummy variable, do a glm or how should I proceed.

Comment: Depends how many levels your categorical variable has, for 2 you can use logistic regression, for more levels (and depending if ordered or not) you have to look for models like multinomial models

Comment: Thank you for your reply @starja it only has 2 levels: 0 not menopaused 1 menopaused.

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to compute changes.  For one thing this assumes you have perfectly transformed the data.  As with your first approach, a Markov process is a good starting place, and you can uncondition on the previous responses if you want unconditional estimates.   This is covered [here](https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19).